# Calculate the coordinates in a circle

Tags: c#, wpf, math

I am drawing an imaginary circle around the middle of a button.

The radius of the circle is the `Height/2` if `Height>Width` or `Width/2` if `Width>Height`.
Now i have to calculate which coordinates (in pixels) are in this circle.
The idea is that if e.g. the mouse cursor hovers over that circle, something happens.

Comment: what did you tried? put some sample code please.

Comment: Your post is unreadable. Could you improve it with using Code tag etc.

Comment: Why use that radius? Maybe you want the circumscribed circle of the rectancle. By the Pythagoras theorem, it's `radius * radius` equals `(height/2) * (width/2)` or `height * width / 4`. So you could check (avoiding integer division) if `4 * (deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY) <= height * width`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are inside the circle when this equation is satisfied:

```
Math.pow(mouse_pos_x-center_circle_x,2)+Math.pow(mouse_pos_y-center_circle_y,2)<Math.pow(radius,2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Calculating each co-ordinate is overkill; just compare the *distance* to the center. For example:

```
int radius = 5; // whatever

int deltaX = originX - mouseX, deltaY = originY - mouseY;

// compare the square distance, to avoid an unnecessary square-root
if((deltaX * deltaX) + (deltaY * deltaY) <= (radius * radius)) {
    // inside the circle, or on the edge
}
```

To avoid a little math, you could also do a quick bounding-box check, i.e. checking the *rectangular* region (just addition/subtraction). This can be used in combination, i.e.

- check the bounding box

  - if it isn't in the bounding box it certainly isn't in the circle
  - if it *is* in the bounding box, do the math to compare the square-distance

Comment: I think the bounding box optimization is slightly overkill once you've reduced the distance calculation to 5 integer operations (square radius can be predetermined), especially since this is in reaction to mouse movement (which can not happen that many times in a second).

Answer (score 1):

The area of a a circle by definition is a group of points whose distance is equal to or less than the center.

All you must do to test if a point is within a circle is to calculate the distance between it and the center point. If this distance is smaller than the radius of the circle, the point is within the circle.

```
double Distance(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    int x = p1.X - p2.X;
    int y = p1.Y - p2.Y;
    return Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);   
}
```

Comment: In most hit-tests, you would simply compare the *square* distance, rather than compute the (relatively expensive) square-root.

Answer (score 1):

You can use next condition:

```
x^2+y^2<R^2
```

Where R - radius,
All this points are in circle.